# saving dates or phone numbers or different characters to mySQL db

Tags: html, mysql

I have a form with a few input boxes like so

```
<input type='text' name='Last' placeholder='Last Name'/>
<input type='text' name='dob' placeholder='Birth Date'/>
<input type='text' name='height' placeholder='Height'/>
```

But if I write in the input box for the date something like 4/8/87 it wont save to the DB. Same situation if I write for the height as 5'7" or the phone number as 702-412-4453 If I write those like that. Nothing will save at all. I have to just write them all generic like 4887 or 57 or 7024124453

Could someone explain why or show me a workaround?

Comment: I think you should check the datatype of those in your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter and clean your input before inserting to DB.

USE mysqli_real_escape_string or any similar function provided by your language  if your not using PHP:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['lastname']);
$age = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['age']);

$sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$age')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

That's from w3school: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp

This will ensure the security of your insert query and will read the variable value as value to be inserted only, and not a part of the query syntax.

for example you insert 5'7:

The query will be:

**WITHOUT ESCAPING:**

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
    VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '5'7')";
```

See the 5'7 ruins the query, so you need to escape it:

```
  $sql="INSERT INTO Persons (FirstName, LastName, Age)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '".mysqli_real_escape_string("5'7")."')";
```

now the 5'7 will not ruin the query because it will be read only as value to be inserted.

Comment: Fantastic!! Perfect answer

Comment: Can you also tag this as PHP please?

Comment: cause its kinda akward your question is about html and mysql, but accepted answer is PHP lol

Answer (score 0):

When saving data like that I recommend that you use the data type [VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html). This will allow you to save the data which you are specifing.

Make sure to have a primary key to link them all together. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BEbKji_pSZM) is a good video tutorial series if you need to learn the basics

Comment: weird thing is... I am using the data type VARCHAR and I do have a primary key.

Comment: Are you sure it's VARCHAR? did you set a limit to the size of the VARCHAR? The primary key is not the reason for this not working but I was just making sure you remember to use one :)

Comment: I just did some more testing. I AM able to save if I do it like 8/13/91 for the date. However, I cannot save if I do the height like 5'8" then nothing saves

Comment: @Kevin1990M you need to escape inputs. read my answer, are you using PHP? tag this as PHP also if yes